# How to get longitude and latitude from firebase real time database and display the location markers in Google Maps API?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am building an android app to track the location of the multiple devices. I did the app to save the longitude and latitude of the devices to the Firebase, but I do not know how to retrieve the longitude and latitude from Firebase and display them as markers in the Google map.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: how do you save the lat and lon? They are likely saved like just 2 double values. SO you need to get them as just 2 double values.

Answer (score 0):

I don't how you can do the `firebase` part, but once you have the information you need to do something like this:

```
LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
```

In the `onMapReady`, to add a new marker with custom values, if you are going to have a lot of markers I'll suggest that you look into `clustering`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    markerOptions.position(latLng);
    markerOptions.title("Current Position");
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_pin_black));
    mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```